# Which is more; even or odd positive factors?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Suppose
 $f(n)=$ $\{$ ( number of $n$'s positive even factors) $-$ (number of  $n$'s positive odd factors) $\}$

How can we prove/disprove the below statement?

> $f(n)< 0 $    for  half or more than numbers from $1$ to $2012^{2013}$

> There is a positive number for $n$ such that $f(n)=2013$

Please edit the question by giving a good language.

Comment: When you say "$(n\text{'s positive even factors})$", do you mean the number of different positive even factors, their sum, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first statement: if $n$ is odd, $n$ has no even factors. Therefore, $f(n) = (0 - \text{number of n's positive odd factors}) \lt 0$ for odd $n$. $2012^{2013}$ is even, so exactly half of the possible $n \in [1, 2012^{2013}]$ are odd, implying that the first statement is true.

Answer (score 4):

For the second statement, let $n=2^{2014}$.

Answer (score 2):

As to the second question, let $n=2^23^{60}5^{10}7^2$.  Then the odd divisors of $n$ are those numbers of the form $3^a\times 5^b\times 7^c$ where $a\in \{0,60\}$, $b\in \{0,10\}$ and $c\in \{0,2\}$.  thus there are $61$ choices for $a$, $11$ for $b$ and $3$ for $c$ so the total number of odd divisors of $n$ is $61\times11\times3=2013$.  As to the even divisors, they are of the form $2d$ or $4d$ where $d$ is an odd divisor of $n$.  Thus there are $2\times 2013$ even divisors.  Hence $f(n)=2013$.

Comment: I think my answer is simpler, but this one has merit as well because it's a *smaller* value of $n$.  One might ask, is it the small*est*?

Comment: @BarryCipra, Yours is definitely simpler!  My goal was certainly to find the smallest, but I didn't think hard about it.  In general, $f(n)$ is a multiple of the number of odd divisors...that should help....

Comment: Please doublecheck this, but I think $n=2^{62}3^{10}5^2$ also works, and is certainly smaller.  The basic idea is that if $n=2^rm$ with $m$ odd having $k$ (odd) divisors, then $n$ has $rk$ even divisors and $k$ odd divisors, so $f(n)=(r-1)k$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Sorry, I missed your edit.  Yes, I agree with your number.